# Add a column to existing table and uniquely number them on MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a *column* to an existing legacy *database* and write a *procedure* by which I can assign each record a different value. Something like adding a *column* and autogenerate the data for it.

Like, if I add a new *column* called "ID" (number) I want to then initialize a unique value to each of the records. So, my ID *column* will have records from say `1 to 1000`.
How do I do that?

Comment: This is going to be database specific.  You should specify what database you're working with.

Comment: You should edit your question to mention that.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

This will depend on the database but for SQL Server, this could be achieved as follows:

```
alter table Example
add NewColumn int identity(1,1)
```

Comment: That worked beautifully and added all the numbers I needed automatically.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have problems making change with the management studio gui you can change the settings under /Tools/Options/Designer/Table and Database Desiger you will find a checkbox `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation` uncheck that box and you will be able to add an identity column even by using the gui.

Answer (score 26):

It would help if you posted what SQL database you're using.  For MySQL you probably want auto_increment:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
```

Not sure if this applies the values retroactively though.  If it doesn't you should just be able to iterate over your values with a stored procedure or in a simple program (as long as no one else is writing to the database) and set use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to generate the id value.

Comment: I may as well confirm that this indeed works for MySQL; I just added an incrementing id field to an existing unindexed table and each row got a unique new id.

Comment: Sorry its an old one but it did say SQL server in the title.

Answer (score 12):

for oracle you could do something like below

```
alter table mytable add (myfield integer);

update mytable set myfield = rownum;
```

Answer (score 11):

And the Postgres equivalent (second line is mandatory only if you want "id" to be a key):

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD id SERIAL;
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just using an ALTER TABLE should work. Add the column with the proper type and an IDENTITY flag and it should do the trick

Check out this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275462(SQL.80).aspx on the ALTER TABLE syntax

Answer (score 4):

for UNIQUEIDENTIFIER datatype in sql server try this

```
Alter table table_name
add ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null unique default(newid())
```

If you want to create primary key out of that column use this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_name PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the database as each database has a different way to add sequence numbers. I would alter the table to add the column then write a db script in groovy/python/etc to read in the data and update the id with a sequence. Once the data has been set, I would add a sequence to the table that starts after the top number. Once the data has been set, set the primary keys correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your new column to be of type `IDENTITY` (auto-increment), or you want to be specific about the order in which your rows are numbered, you can add a column of type `INT NULL` and then populate it like this.  In my example, the new column is called MyNewColumn and the existing primary key column for the table is called MyPrimaryKey.

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyTable.MyNewColumn = AutoTable.AutoNum
FROM
(
    SELECT MyPrimaryKey, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn, SomeOtherColumn) AS AutoNum
    FROM MyTable 
) AutoTable
WHERE MyTable.MyPrimaryKey = AutoTable.MyPrimaryKey
```

This works in SQL Sever 2005 and later, i.e. versions that support `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure column name is Id.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD Id int identity(1,1)
```