# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Row numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, r

Backstory:  I'm using `SQL Server` because my data set is ~ 150 columns wide and I don't feel like typing all of that into `MySql Workbench` table setup.  So I'm using the `MS SQL Server` data import tool.

I'm trying to set the table up so that I can downsample the data in `R`.  I'm planning on pulling all the positives (~100k) and then pulling a random sample of ~400k from the non-positives.  To do this I need a row numbering column to index positives and non-positives.

In `MySQL` I'd just add a row numbering column when setting up the table, but I don't know how to do that in `SQL Server's` data import tool.  I've already built the table and would prefer to add it (or know if `SQL Server` already has assigned row numbers) but am willing to rebuild the table as it's not useable without row numbers.

EDIT: I need to know how to do this in SSMS or directly in the import tool.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function. Either use it in your queries, or you could write an update statement that, based on ROW_NUMBER(), updates the rows in your table.

If you don't care about ordering when assigning row numbers, you could also just add a new integer auto incrementing column to the table. In order to do that, add a new IDENTITY column to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

[Add a column to existing table and uniquely number them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108211/sql-server-add-a-column-to-existing-table-and-uniquely-number-them)

Comment: how do i add a new integer auto incrementing column? I'm using the SSMS.  When I add a column I can name it and make it an INT and NOT NULL but can't find the auto-increment setting.

Comment: I don't have SSMS handy here, but it should be there in the UI... I can check later.

Comment: I updated the answer with the script way of adding the column - which you should be using anyways ;-)

Comment: perfect, I ran the script and it worked.  Thank you very much.