# How to bulk load data such without entering values for the column indexed "auto-increment"

Tags: mysql

Following is the code to bulk load data from a text file.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\file.txt'
    INTO TABLE datatable;
```

I have a table with two columns, an attribute and `id`, *the primary key with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` index*. Values for the attribute are given (one line for each row) in the text file.

**I want the id (indexed "AUTO_INCREMENT) to be inserted itself and then increment itself**. I think it is possible, but **what will be the way to do it?**

Comment: And Now I would like to suggest you instead posting too many question at each step too quickly, put some efforts yourself. Pick some book/manual and read them.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I am reading a tutorial, and posting whatever questions come to my mind. I do a quick Google search and try something hands-on before posting as well.

Comment: It is time to choose better references, and put some more efforts. Try yourself to find your answer first that will help you better.

Comment: @Zarah Two people (including me) gave you answers for your question as a voluntary service. Next time be fair and at least give a little feedback, please. thanks!

Comment: @Robert I actually thought that I had marked the answer as accepted, but I missed it. Just gave my feedback, and I your solution, that is to import the file seemed a bit complex to me; I am a beginner just trying to learn basic SQL and MySQL, so I don't think it will be good idea to jump to a new thing when a simpler thing is already not working. But I am just going to try what you suggested, thank you for the knowledge.

Comment: @Zarah I regularly read some Q & As from "http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/hot" similarly I read hotQ&A on other tags to improve my skills

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Although the link returns a "page not found", but I'll take up your suggestion, thank you very much for sharing.

Comment: @Zarah It was links hot questions [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/hot) In url if you replace 'mysql' with any other tag then it will query for corresponding tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\file.txt'
    INTO TABLE datatable(`attribute`);
```

If this won't work, a table structure and a sample rows of your file.txt would help.

Answer (score 2):

You could raw import everything from `.txt` into the Database (with your given command), so you have just the attributes there and then **afterwards add the `ID` field later**.

```
ALTER TABLE datatable ADD `id` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
```

For detail explanation there is already a question for that:
[Add a column to existing table and uniquely number them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108211/sql-server-add-a-column-to-existing-table-and-uniquely-number-them)