# SQL - Append Identity Column in Existing Temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update my temp table records. But my existing Temp table does not have any unique column. So I need to append Identity column and update all the records based on that Identity column.

For example, If my temp table has 1000 records without any unique column values. I need to number all these 1000 records and update values.

```
while(@count < identity_value)
begin
update #temp
Name = 'Gold'
where identity = @count
@count = @count+1
End
```

I can Alter table option but in my case records are already inserted into my temp table. So I need to loop thorugh it by adding Identity column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a column to existing table and uniquely number them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108211/add-a-column-to-existing-table-and-uniquely-number-them)

Comment: So the only reason for adding an identity column is so you can then go through and update every row individually? Why not just use `update #temp set Name = 'Gold'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do an `UPDATE`. The identity column is going to be populated when it is created. All you need is:

```
ALTER TABLE #temp
ADD Id INT Identity(1, 1)
GO
```

`Id` field will be populated and it will hold values `1, 2, ..., 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loops. See this simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    Name varchar(10)
)
INSERT #temp VALUES ('A'),('B')

--Add identity column
ALTER TABLE #temp ADD ID int IDENTITY
```

Answer (score 1):

It may add value to add the identity column as a clustered primary key to make the table more efficient.

```
ALTER TABLE #temp ADD Id int Identity(1, 1) primary key clustered;
```