# How to add 1 to the previous month's record and insert it as a current month record?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

My table structure is like below

```
id     month      year  dummyval
11     January    2017  1
12     January    2017  1
13     January    2017  2
```

I am inserting next month to this table but I also want to insert a dummyval for each id. Like the table should be-

```
id     month       year  dummyval
11     January     2017  1
12     January     2017  1
13     January     2017  2
11     February    2017  2
12     February    2017  2
13     February    2017  3
```

How to do that? Please help.

Comment: Try adding new column (here's how to do it):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108211/add-a-column-to-existing-table-and-uniquely-number-them

Next, add desired values using UPDATE command.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I don't want to add any new column. What I want to do is whatever is my last month's dummy value I just want to increment it by 1 and that value I want to add as my next month's record for each id.

Comment: Do you really have the month names stored in your table, instead of there integer representations (1 for January, 2 for February and so on?)

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Yes... I am storing month name instead of number

Comment: OK, let me work on it... I assume `id` is autoincrement, correct?

Comment: Are you allowed to create a (small) table in the database to make your life easier?

Comment: yes @GiorgosAltanis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you store the month name in your code, you need to have a way to find the next month name. To keep it simple (but somewhat lengthy), I would begin by defining an auxiliary data structure to hold basic month information:

```
create table months (monthid int, monthname varchar(20));
insert into months (monthid, monthname)
select 1, 'January' union all
select 2, 'February' union all
select 3, 'March' union all
/*... all other months*/
select 12, 'December';
```

Suppose now that your max year-month value in your table (call it 'data') is 2017/January. You could use the following code to find the next year-month-dummyval combination and insert it into your table, without having to know beforehand which records you need to insert (and their ids):

```
/* a temporary table to hold "next month" info. It should be avoided using a 
join, but I failed miserably in my attempt! */
create temporary table next_month (monthid int, monthname varchar(20), next_id int, next_name varchar(20));

insert into next_month (monthid, monthname, next_id)
select monthid, monthname, case when monthid = 12 then 1 else monthid + 1 end
from months;

update next_month set next_name = 
 (select monthname from months where months.monthid = next_month.next_id);
```

Now you are ready to insert your new data:

```
insert into data (month, year, dummyval)
select 
  next_month.next_name, 
  case when months.monthid = 12 then data.year + 1 else data.year end,
  data.dummyval + 1
from data join months on data.month = months.monthname 
join next_month on months.monthid = next_month.monthid
where data.month = 'January' and data.year = 2017;
```

Comment: The `months` table will also help you determine the maximum year-month value in your table: select max(year*100 + months.monthid) from data join months on data.month = months.monthname;

Comment: Thanks. But this method is indeed lengthy. I have found another solution and which is working fine.

Comment: I am happy for you, take care!

Comment: still thank you so much. I learnt new insert query from you too :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
insert into table1 select id , 'February', 2017, dummyval+1 from table1  
where id=11;
```

with each insert you do..

Here's an example:

```
mysql> select * from K3;
+------+------+
| name | val  |
+------+------+
| x    | 1    |
| y    | 2    |
+------+------+
```

INSERTING:

```
insert into K3 select 'g', val+1 from K3 where name='x';
```

AFTER INSERT:

```
mysql> select * from K3;
+------+------+
| name | val  |
+------+------+
| x    | 1    |
| y    | 2    |
| g    | 2    |
+------+------+
```

You can see that it has inserted 'g' with 2, incremented from x's 1

Comment: Will it add 1 to the previous value?

Comment: yes, as long as you specify the where correctly. Let me add an example.

Comment: @Prady: Added an example.

Comment: I got your example @KrishnaKumar.

Comment: Let me try this one and Let you know if it works... Thank you @Krishnakumar

Comment: @Prady :: Glad to help :)

Comment: INSERT INTO dummytable1 SELECT MONTHNAME(CURDATE()),dummyvalue+1 WHERE (SELECT id FROM dummytable2 GROUP BY id);

Comment: I tried this but getting error dummyvalue is unknown column in field list

Comment: @Prady maybe you didn't have the dummy value column in the table. In you example u have given the column name as dummyval

Comment: @Prady And why do you have two tables here? dummytable1 and dummytable2? According to ur question, you have one table dummytable1 and you need to insert into the same table

Comment: Yes in example it is dummyval but actual the column name is dummyvalue.

Comment: @Prady
More over your query should be:

`INSERT INTO dummytable1 SELECT MONTHNAME(CURDATE()),dummyvalue+1 from dummytable1 WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM dummytable1 GROUP BY id);`

if I understand your question correctly...
you left the 'id in' part in the where condition and the 'from table' part. and the table should be the same

Comment: This query worked but now the problem is... It is inserting more than a single time... like if i have record of january and february month for 1, 2, 3 id then it is inserting record of march by adding 1 in january month and adding 1 in february month where as i want to add 1 for previous month only... can you help me for this? @Krishnakumar

Comment: Thank you so much your query helped me a lot. I found my own solution for previous month value increment and that is  'INSERT INTO dummytable1(id,MONTH,YEAR,dummyvalue) SELECT id,MONTHNAME(CURDATE()),YEAR(CURDATE()),dummyvalue+1 FROM dummytable1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM dummytable2 GROUP BY id) AND dummyvalue IN(SELECT dummyvalue FROM dummytable1 WHERE MONTH=MONTHNAME((CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)));' This one is giving a result which exactly I want. Thank you :)

Comment: @Prady :: Just came back.. Glad you got what u wanted... Vote up this answer as it helped you ?