# SQL Server : join tables based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and wanted to make a join and extracting the target output. but I'm not getting the desired results as shown in the image.

[image]

My query:

```
select  
    a.catalog_number,
    a.catalog_image,
    b.catalog_description 
from 
    catalog_type a
inner join
    catalog_description b on a.catalog_number = b.catalog_number
```

Comments: I should get 3 rows but the query returns 9 rows based on the join condition.

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: On your image it looks like the table name is `catelog_description`

Comment: Try changing the "inner join" to "left join"

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @ideaztech that will not solve the problem.

Comment: OP. How is it that YOU know that `catalog_image` `IMG-855001` should have description `Timely Updating`. I can't see any reason why you would pick that description over `Storing/Organizing`. In fact I think your choice is wrong and mine is right.

Comment: OK, now that I see your image of sample data, the problem is the catalog_number is not unique.  You are linking the tables on a a field that repeats, so it will multiply the link.  You should asign a unique ID to the catalog table and link to that.  Or make catalog_number unique.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data. Please paste them in as `code` blocks or |Tables| respectively

Answer (score 1):

I see many problems on your question.

1. The tables named on the query are not the same on the picture, so i don't know if you write wrong the query or your image is not right.
2. If i replace the table "catalog_details" from the query with catalog_description from image the total rows returned will be 9 no 6.

[image]

So, your problem is in the model, or your conception about the model and the data, not in the query.

To get something like the result that you show on the image, you need some like this.
[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data. Please paste them in as `code` blocks or |Tables| respectively

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table Catalog_Type add Catalog_Type_ID int identity(1,1)

alter table Catalog_description add Catalog_Description_ID int identity(1,1)

select ct.catalag_number, ct.catalog_image,cd.catalog_description 
from Catalog_Type as ct 
inner join Catalog_description cd 
on cd.Catalog_Description_ID = ct.Catalog_Type_ID
```

[Add a column to existing table and uniquely number them on MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108211/add-a-column-to-existing-table-and-uniquely-number-them-on-ms-sql-server)

You can check in this link how to add Id column to table.